# Exclude an array

Tags: wp-query, media

I'm moving edit post dashboard to front end.
So here is a case, I have to queries, one for product attachments and other for ALL.

Now, I want to exclude product attachments from ALL attachments query

here is an example how to exclude post thumbnail from WordPress Codex:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()
    );

$attachments = get_posts( $args );

if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
        the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, false );
    }
}

?>
```

before that, I have a query of all products, so can `exclude` take array argument? For example with my code

```
$mediaArgs = array(
    'post_type'         => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type'    => 'image',
    'numberposts'       => -1,
    'post_status'       => null,
    'post_parent'       => $current_post,
);
$MediaAttachments = get_posts($mediaArgs);
```

Can I then foreach this and save MediaAttachment->ID inside some array and exclude put it next tu `exclude`? In my theory it should work as usual, but no matter how I tried, it does not work.

Comment: Looking at [the relevant code (`wp-includes/post.php`)](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/post.php), it appears that your 'exclude' list gets passed to a function called [`wp_parse_id_list()`](http://wpseek.com/wp_parse_id_list/), which accepts arrays. How have you tried generating your `$exclude` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange but it works with same principle I was trying to. Maybe I had some grammer error. Here is a code if somebody will need it in future as there was nothing in search result:

```
// get product media library
$mediaArgs = array(
    'post_type'         => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type'    => 'image',
    'numberposts'       => -1,
    'post_status'       => null,
    'post_parent'       => $current_post, // any parent
);
$MediaAttachments = get_posts($mediaArgs);

$parentMediaArray = array();
foreach ($MediaAttachments as $MediaAttachment) {
    $parentMediaArray[] = $MediaAttachment->ID;
}
// get ALL the media library exept that I'm using now
$mediaArgs2 = array(
    'post_type'         => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type'    => 'image',
    'numberposts'       => -1,
    'post_status'       => null,
    'exclude'           => $parentMediaArray,
    'post_parent'       => 'any', // any parent
);
$MediaAttachmentsALL = get_posts($mediaArgs2);
```

Where `$parentMediaArray` is the array which I exclude